# [vue]use semantic.min.css icon font error: Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:10001/font/icons.woff2

Tags: fonts, decode, semantic-ui, vuejs2

App.vue, import semantic css, and I download font from google to local

```
<style lang="stylus">
    @import './asset/semantic-ui/semantic.min.css';
</style>
```

[image]

https://github.com/Dreampie/vuejs2-demo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if download from https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS/archive/master.zip font broken,please
download from here it's ok: http://semantic-ui.com/dist/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff2

beacause font file broken，do not use unrelease version